# c++ gcc inline assembly does not seem to work

Tags: c++, assembly, inline, intel, masm

I am trying to figure out gcc inline assembly on c++. The following code works on visual c++ without % and other operands but i could not make it work with gcc

```
void function(const char* text) {
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)text;
    DWORD fncAddr = 0x004169E0;
        asm(
        "push %0" "\n"
        "call %1" "\n"
        "add esp, 04" "\n"
        : "=r" (addr) : "d" (fncAddr)
    );
}
```

I am injecting a dll to a process on runtime and fncAddr is an address of a function. It never changes. As I said it works with Visual C++

VC++ equivalent of that function:

```
void function(const char* text) {
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)text;
    DWORD fncAddr = 0x004169E0;
    __asm {
        push addr
        call fncAddr
        add esp, 04
    }
}
```

Edit:
I changed my function to this: now it crashes

```
void sendPacket(const char* msg) {
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)msg;
    DWORD fncAddr = 0x004169E0;

        asm(
        ".intel_syntax noprefix" "\n"
        "pusha" "\n"
        "push %0" "\n"
        "call %1" "\n"
        "add esp, 04" "\n"
        "popa" "\n"
        :
        : "r" (addr) , "d"(fncAddr) : "memory"
    );
}
```

Edit:

```
004169E0  /$ 8B0D B4D38100  MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[81D3B4]
004169E6  |. 85C9           TEST ECX,ECX
004169E8  |. 74 0A          JE SHORT client_6.004169F4
004169EA  |. 8B4424 04      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4]
004169EE  |. 50             PUSH EAX
004169EF  |. E8 7C3F0000    CALL client_6.0041A970
004169F4  \> C3             RETN
```

the function im calling is above. I changed it to function pointer cast

```
char_func_t func = (char_func_t)0x004169E0;
func(text);
```

like this and it crashed too but surprisingly somethimes it works. I attacted a debugger and it gave access violation at some address it does not exist

on callstack the last call is this:

```
004169EF  |. E8 7C3F0000    CALL client_6.0041A970
```

LAST EDIT:

I gave up inline assembly, instead i wrote instructions i wanted byte by byte and it works like a charm

```
void function(const char* text) {
    DWORD fncAddr = 0x004169E0;

    char *buff = new char[50]; //extra bytes for no reason
    memset((void*)buff, 0x90, 50);
    *((BYTE*)buff) = 0x68; // push
    *((DWORD*)(buff + 1)) = ((DWORD)text);
    *((BYTE*)buff+5) = 0xE8; //call
    *((DWORD*)(buff + 6)) = ((DWORD)fncAddr) - ((DWORD)&(buff[5]) + 5);
    *((BYTE*)(buff + 10)) = 0x83; // add esp, 04
    *((BYTE*)(buff + 11)) = 0xC4;
    *((BYTE*)(buff + 12)) = 0x04;
    *((BYTE*)(buff + 13)) = 0xC3; // ret
    typedef void(*char_func_t)(void);
    char_func_t func = (char_func_t)buff;
    func();
    delete[] buff;
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: *Why* are you dabbling in inline asm *at all*? Doesn't your optimizing compiler generate good enough code for you? Do you have a *special* use case where this *needs* to be super hyper optimized? In most cases I'd say "don't bother" - you'll probably do worse than the compiler anyway and even if you do better it will probably not actually matter anyway.

Comment: It works in Visual C++ because VC ignores the `asm` keyword.

Comment: I'm not even going to attempt to figure out what you are doing and why. and the pitfalls with calling a function from inline assembly (clobbers etc). But `"add esp, 04"` is probably meant to be `"add $4, %%esp"`

Comment: Why am I dabbling with it? Obviously I need it alright. I am not trying to create a super uber optimized code. I said I am injecting this to a process which i didn't create nor I don't have its source code. Its just a game and I am trying to call one of its function on runtime thats all. VC doesnt ignore asm keyword, I use its own asm keywords which is __asm and it works as expected. I don't know how gcc works thats why I asked this

Comment: I use intel assembly  I added -masm=intel

Comment: OK, I added vc++ equivalent of the code

Comment: And how does it fail. Did you attach a debugger to see what might be wrong? Are you sure it is this code that is failing?

Comment: The game responses when its called and It doesnt do anything or does not crash

Comment: If you are going to list clobbers for any volatile registers that the function may modify you might consider putting a `pusha` at the beginning of the assembly code and `popa` at the end. I don't know the calling convention of the function being called so pushing them all and restoring is quick and dirty.

Comment: The other problem if this is compiled with optimizations on is that the string `text` may not be realized into memory by simply passing the address through a register with `"=r"` . GCC will passes the address of the string but since you don't say you are using whats at that address the compiler can avoid having the string in memory at this point. Quick and dirty fix for that is adding `: "memory"` to the end (add a clobber list).

Comment: Just noticed something else very important. If you are compiling with optimizations this code could be entirely optimized away because you have an output constraint for a variable that is tossed away so you should be using `asm volatile` not just `asm` . Although I do wonder why you have `"=r" (addr)` to begin with since the address won't be changing. Probably should pass this as an input constraint rather than an output constraint.

Comment: the compiler says i must add =

Comment: Input operands, output operand, and clobbers are all separated with a colon (`:`) . If you have no output operands you would do something like  `: : "r" (addr), "d" (fncAddr) : "memory"` .

Comment: And that is probably part of the problem all along. You meant to use `addr` as an input operand, but you specified an output operand only. That means the register upon entry to the assembly template may have undefined stuff in it since you didn't tell the compiler you needed the value as input just that you'd be overwriting it.

Comment: Regarding your last snippet of code. Personally I'm wondering if there is some issue with calling convention stdcall cdecl that is a problem? I sense that possibly you are having some other kind of issue. Are you sure the address you are calling is still correct? How is sendPacket called? Are you sure that the function you are calling isn't modifying the string?

Comment: How does an extra layer of trampoline help?  Does the function you're calling clobber stack memory?  Was it a calling-convention mismatch you could solve with `__attribute__((cdecl))`?  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).  Your solution is obviously terrible for performance (new/delete, and writing the machine code every time guarantees an I-cache miss.  I think you might be safe against a self-modifying-code machine clear, though). So I guess speed doesn't matter for your use-case.  Anyway, post answers as answers, not as edits to the question.

Comment: Would you provide us a complete disassembly of this MSVC code from your question: `void function(const char* text) {
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)text;
    DWORD fncAddr = 0x004169E0;
    __asm {
        push addr
        call fncAddr
        add esp, 04
    }
}` .

Answer (score 0):

Your current version with `pusha` / `popa` looks correct (slow but safe), unless your calling convention depends on maintaing 16-byte stack alignment.

**If it's crashing, your real problem is somewhere else, so you should use a debugger and find out *where* it crashes**.

Declaring clobbers on `eax` / `ecx` / `edx`, or asking for the pointers in two of those registers and clobbering the third, would let you avoid `pusha` / `popa`.  (Or whatever the call-clobbered regs are for the calling convention you're using.)

You should remove the `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  You already depend on compiling with `-masm=intel`, because you don't restore the previous mode in case it was AT&T.  (I don't think there is a way to save/restore the old mode, unfortunately, but there is [a dialect-alternatves mechanism](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Multiple-assembler-dialects-in-asm-templates) for using different templates for different syntax modes.)

---

### You don't need and shouldn't use inline asm for this

**compilers know how to make function calls already, when you're using a standard calling convention** (in this case: stack args in 32-bit mode which is normally the default).

**It's valid C++ to cast an integer to a function pointer**, and it's not even undefined behaviour if there really is a function there at that address.

```
void function(const char* text) {
    typedef void (*char_func_t)(const char *);
    char_func_t func = (char_func_t)0x004169E0;
    func(text);
}
```

As a bonus, this compiles more efficiently with MSVC than your asm version, too.

**You can use GCC function attributes on function pointers to specify the calling convention explicitly**, in case you compile with a different default.  For example [`__attribute__((cdecl))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) to explicitly specify stack args and caller-pops for calls using that function pointer.  The MSVC equivalent is just [`__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/cdecl).

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  #define CDECL   __attribute__((cdecl))
  #define STDCALL __attribute__((stdcall))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
  #define CDECL   __cdecl
  #define STDCALL __stdcall
#else
  #define CDECL   /*empty*/
  #define STDCALL /*empty*/
#endif

// With STDCALL instead of CDECL, this function has to translate from one calling convention to another
// so it can't compile to just a jmp tailcall
void function(const char* text) {
    typedef void (CDECL *char_func_t)(const char *);
    char_func_t func = (char_func_t)0x004169E0;
    func(text);
}
```

---

**To see the compiler's asm output**, I put this [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23ifdef+__GNUC__%0A%23define+CDECL+++__attribute__((cdecl))%0A%23define+STDCALL+__attribute__((stdcall))%0A%23elif+defined(_MSC_VER)%0A%23define+CDECL+++__cdecl%0A%23define+STDCALL+__stdcall%0A%23else%0A%23define+CDECL+++/*empty*/%0A%23define+STDCALL+/*empty*/%0A%23endif%0A%0A//+With+STDCALL+instead+of+CDECL,+this+function+has+to+translate+from+one+calling+convention+to+another%0A//+so+it+can!'t+compile+to+just+a+jmp+tailcall%0Avoid+function(const+char*+text)+%7B%0A++++typedef+void+(CDECL+*char_func_t)(const+char+*)%3B%0A++++char_func_t+func+%3D+(char_func_t)0x004169E0%3B%0A++++func(text)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+caller()+%7B%0A++++function(%22hello+world%22)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A//%23include+%3Cwindows.h%3E%0Atypedef+int+DWORD%3B%0A%0Avoid+function_asm(const+char*+text)+%7B%0A++++DWORD+addr+%3D+(DWORD)text%3B%0A++++DWORD+fncAddr+%3D+0x004169E0%3B%0A++++__asm+%7B%0A++++++++push+addr%0A++++++++call+fncAddr%0A++++++++add+esp,+04%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+caller_asm()+%7B%0A++++function_asm(%22hello+world%22)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.125033094034144,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:29.271296430604245,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_32,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ox',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:33.60367047536161,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  I used the "intel-syntax" option, so gcc output comes from `gcc -S -masm=intel`

```
# gcc8.1 -O3 -m32   (the 32-bit Linux calling convention is close enough to Windows)
#  except it requires maintaing 16-byte stack alignment.

function(char const*):
        mov     eax, 4286944
        jmp     eax            # tail-call with the args still where we got them
```

**This test caller makes the compiler set up args and not just a tail-call**, but `function` can inline into it.

```
int caller() {
    function("hello world");
    return 0;
}


.LC0:
        .string "hello world"
caller():
        sub     esp, 24             # reserve way more stack than it needs to reach 16-byte alignment, IDK why.
        mov     eax, 4286944        # your function pointer
        push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0    # addr becomes an immediate
        call    eax
        xor     eax, eax            # return 0
        add     esp, 28             # add esp, 4 folded into this
        ret
```

MSVC's `-Ox` output for `caller` is essentially the same:

```
caller PROC
    push     OFFSET $SG2661
    mov      eax, 4286944       ; 004169e0H
    call     eax
    add      esp, 4
    xor      eax, eax
    ret      0
```

**But a version using your inline asm is much worse**:

```
;; MSVC -Ox on a caller() that uses your asm implementation of function()
caller_asm PROC
    push     ebp
    mov      ebp, esp
    sub      esp, 8
                           ; store inline asm inputs to the stack
    mov      DWORD PTR _addr$2[ebp], OFFSET $SG2671
    mov      DWORD PTR _fncAddr$1[ebp], 4286944 ; 004169e0H

    push     DWORD PTR _addr$2[ebp]      ; then reload as memory operands
    call     DWORD PTR _fncAddr$1[ebp]
    add      esp, 4

    xor      eax, eax
    mov      esp, ebp             ; makes the add esp,4 redundant in this case
    pop      ebp
    ret      0
```

MSVC inline asm syntax basically sucks, because unlike GNU C asm syntax the inputs always have to be in memory, not registers or immediates.  So you could do better with GNU C, but not as good as you can do by avoiding inline asm altogether.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.

Making function calls from inline asm is generally to be avoided; it's much safer and more efficient when the compiler knows what's happening.

Comment: I hate it when people downvote correct answers because they don't like the question.  That's not how SO voting works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I haven't upvoted this. One thing is that there is more to this fellows problems than what you present here. You show a method to simplify things that will in all likelihood still crash his code as presented in his last code snippet. Why would his last example code crash?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That's true, to me the update looks more or less equivalent to the MSVC  code, especially if stack alignment isn't the issue.   (Except is passes a pointer arg to the inline asm without telling the compiler the memory will be read, so maybe `*addr` hasn't been written yet).  That sounds like a separate debugging question because we don't have a [mcve] for it.  The OP claims the MSVC code works, and I'm showing code that produces equivalent asm with g++, therefore it's an answer to the question as asked.  (And may help debugging to know that the gcc code isn't the problem.)

Comment: We don't know how he's compiling his code under MSVC and whether he overrode the default calling convention with options etc. There is in fact a possibility that whatever bug he has becomes an issue with this code, but it actually because of some other outside factor. Is why early on in the comments I asked him if he attached a debugger to test things. The other possibility is that his MSVC code is wrong but appears to work. Very hard to tell when we don't have the target function code he is calling.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Good point, I guess I could specify `__declspec(cdecl)` or something for the function pointer `#ifdef _MSC_VER`.  I'm not aware of how to get gcc to use different 32-bit Windows calling conventions, though.  There's  `__attribute__((ms_abi))`, but I think that's about it.

Comment: My best hunch on what is really going on? In a comment he says he's doing DLL injection. The code he is showing here is likely inside a DLL that was injected into the target process that his function is calling to. It is possible that however he is building this DLL with GCC isn't correct. I'm suggesting this might be an XY problem. Maybe it is "Building a Windows DLL with GCC doesn't work as expected when injected into a target process"

Comment: @MichaelPetch: updated this answer with a new top section pointing out that the inline-asm in the question should work.

Comment: Well it should work, but to be sure  passing a dummy argument to ensure the string will be in memory wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It has a `"memory"` clobber which I didn't notice before.  It's safe because gcc knows that `addr` is an input, so the memory clobber will affect it.

Comment: Something about your edit is that we are assuming we know the calling covention in the target process which might may or may not conform to a specific convention. What are the volatiles? which aren't etc? The pusha and popa would at least mitigate that.

Comment: Oh that's right I forgot I had him add "memory" for that very purpose in the comments under his question.

Answer (score -4):

Here's an example of inline assembly with gcc.

Routine "vazio" hosts assembly code for routine "rotina" (vazio and rotina are simply labels). Note the use of Intel syntax by means of a directive; gcc defaults to AT&T  .

I recovered this code from an old sub-directory; variables in assembly code were prefixed with "_" , as "_str" - that's standard C convention. I confess that, here and now, I have no idea as why the compiler is accepting "str" instead... Anyway:

compiled correctly with gcc/g++ versions 5 and 7! Hope this helps. Simply call "gcc main.c", or "gcc -S main.c" if you want to see the asm result, and "gcc -S masm=intel main.c" for Intel output.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    char str[] = "abcdefg";

// C routine, acts as a container for "rotina"
void vazio (void) {

    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix");
    asm("rotina:");
    asm("inc eax");

   //  EBX = address of str
    asm("lea ebx, str");

   // ++str[0]
   asm("inc byte ptr [ebx]");

    asm("ret");
    asm(".att_syntax noprefix");
}


// global variables make things simpler
int a;

int main(void) {

    a = -7;

    puts ("antes");
    puts (str);
    printf("a = %d\n\n", a);

    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix");

   asm("mov eax, 0");

    asm("call rotina");

    // modify variable a
    asm("mov a, eax");

    asm(".att_syntax noprefix");

    printf("depois: \n a = %d\n", a);

   puts (str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of how to use GNU C inline asm correctly.  See tutorials and guides in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.  You need all your instructions to be part of one big `asm` statement, and you have to tell the compiler about registers you clobber.  Also, if you want to write a whole function in asm, put your `asm("");` statement at global scope instead of inside another function.  Or use a separate file!