# Call Function From Address

Tags: c++, assembly

i have this asm function call

```
push ebx                                            | Lenght Of Buf
lea eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp]                          |
push eax                                            | Address To Write Crypted Buf
push dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                          | Address Of Orignal Buf
mov ecx,edi                                         |
call 0x008EC40E                                     | crypter function
```

i need to call this function from my Dll(C++) injected to target
some thing like that not work

```
typedef int func(void* Source, void* Dest, int len);
func* f = (func*)(base + 0x341E38);
int i = f(Src, Dst, sizeof Dst);
```

i don't know my C++ is correct or no, so pls help.
i need to correct c++ call, after i run this code target process crash

That's my function body

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
xor eax,eax
cmp byte ptr ds:[ecx+C],al
je lordsco.8EC44E
cmp dword ptr ds:[ecx],eax
je lordsco.8EC44E
cmp dword ptr ss:[ebp+C],eax
je lordsco.8EC44E
cmp dword ptr ss:[ebp+8],eax
je lordsco.8EC44E
cmp dword ptr ss:[ebp+10],eax
jle lordsco.8EC44E
push 1
lea eax,dword ptr ds:[ecx+8]    
push eax
lea eax,dword ptr ds:[ecx+15]
push eax
add ecx,20
push ecx
push dword ptr ss:[ebp+10]
push dword ptr ss:[ebp+C]
push dword ptr ss:[ebp+8]
call lordsco.996560
add esp,1C
mov al,1
jmp lordsco.8EC450
xor al,al
pop ebp
ret C
```

and that what IDA Pro Declare the function

```
char __thiscall CaypterFunc(int this, int a2, int a3, int a4)
```

And that Func call this func

```
int *__cdecl CaypterFunc2(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int *a6, int a7)
```

That's is a Encryption Buffer for game before use in send func
so i need to Encryption my custom buffer and us it in send func

so, what u see .?

Comment: So you're trying to call that asm which in turn just makes a function call?  Why not cut out the middle man and call directly from C++, by declaring the calling convention for a function pointer = 0x008EC40E?   See [c++ gcc inline assembly does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51163770) for how to specify that in MSVC or GNU C.  (Looks like `thiscall` with args in ECX then stack, not EDX so not `fastcall`).

Comment: If that asm snippet is a function you want to call, IDK how to get a compiler to put an arg in EBX or EDI; that's super weird.  Although clearly you're leaving out its function prologue because it needs EBP, and doesn't end with `ret` or a tailcall `jmp`.

Comment: I've tweaked the question

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: it's not my application, i try to hack a game

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the EULA for the game allow you to do such a thing? Anyway, there are two ways; either match the call convention (which IDA detects as `__thiscall`), or use a wrapper and just use the call you provided. BTW, since this is a member function, you'll need the object instance to call it anyway, which you failed to provide in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function signature:

```
typedef int func(void* Source, void* Dest, int len);
```

Is simply wrong, or rather, inadequate for the function you want to call. IDA identifies this as a `__thiscall`, so it's (most likely) a C++ member function. This means that the call needs to pass arguments on the stack, and put the `this` pointer into `ecx`:

```
push ebx                                            | Lenght Of Buf
lea eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp]                          |
push eax                                            | Address To Write Crypted Buf
push dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                          | Address Of Orignal Buf

mov ecx,edi                                         | <<< "this" pointer set here

call 0x008EC40E
```

So a C++ declaration would be closer to something like

```
class Something;
typedef int (Something::*func)(void* Source, void* Dest, int len);
```

You still need to find out what "something" is, or at least get the `this` pointer on which the member function should be called (which in your provided code resides in `edi`, but of course we have no idea how it got there).

Comment: You can make the func pointer declaration include the calling convention explicitly: in MSVC, `typedef int (__thiscall  Something::*func)(void* Source, void* Dest, int len);`.  In GNU C++, `typedef int (__attribute__((thiscall))  Something::*func)(void* Source, void* Dest, int len);`.  (The GNU attribute can go in other places, but it does work in the same place that MSVC requires it, so that makes it easy to `#define` a macro for it.)  See [c++ gcc inline assembly does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51163770) for an #ifdef block.